# Execute while inside function every minute, after a minute c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.2

I have an Initializer inside a class with a lot of thread, so sleep won't be good.
There is also a while with a cap of `uptime` that I'm trying to limit, inside this while I want to run a check that will run after a minute from the moment the app is up, and every minute since, is `System.Timers.Timer` the way to do it? It's important to note that the method activated may cause the app to restart.

```
static public void Initializer(){
//// some code with lots of threads
  while (computerUptimeCommandInMinutes < 15)
    {
      int interval = 60 * 1000;
      System.Timers.Timer runDriversCheckEveryMinuteTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
      runDriversCheckEveryMinuteTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
      runDriversCheckEveryMinuteTimer.Start();
    }
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  myMethod();
}
```

I don't have `.NET6`

Comment: Why are you spamming timers?

Comment: which .net version do you use? and what kind of project? possible solutions depends...

Comment: JoeGER94   I'm working with .NetFrameWork  4.7.2. 3.5 and 4.6.2, Its work related so this is naturally a more complex code than presented

Comment: @MickyD if you have a better solution, I would appreciate it.

Comment: _"if you have a better solution, I would appreciate it"_ - well, **not** spamming timers is a good start.  `1` is enough.  Also, depending on what you intend to do, instead of sleeping/ticking, why not use _Windows Task Scheduler_.  It has a rather nice managed API.

Comment: Since you're using .NET Framework you'll also be running this on Windows... add another vote for doing this with _Windows Task Scheduler_. It contains a lot of features already and can run a command/program on a regular interval, and be enabled/disabled easily. P.S. there are also similar ways to do this on *nix

Comment: Actually this is going to be run on Balena - a cloud linux based system

Comment: @Yuki1112 Balena can run Net Framework code? I doubt that. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

since your description is not clear, I can just try to show a possible Solution

I would use a BackgroundService, which is especially for designed for scenarios like that.

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    Timer? _timer = null;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void DoWork(object? state)
    {
        //do your worke here
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If this Code does not 100 percent match your needs, then it maybe can give you a good idea how to start. e.g. you don't need IHostedService in your case. Just put it into a Task

Comment: I do need to limit it according to how long the computer is running. hence I keep running the timer on the wile

Comment: OP is not using .NET Core and/or NET 5+

Comment: @Yuki1112 first of all you can limit the timer and if you want to protect the code getting executed by another task than you can maybe use a semaphore ?? Timer is available below .net5